# External monitor not detected through HDMI. Ubuntu 22.10. AMD

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, amdgpu

I have an external monitor that I'm connecting to my Huawei Laptop

```
Model: HUAWEI NBLK-WAX9X, 
RAM: 8.0 GiB, 
CPU: AMD Ryzen™ 5 3500U with Radeon™ Vega Mobile Gfx × 8
GPU: AMD Radeon™ Vega 8 Graphics,
OS: Ubuntu 22.10,
OS Type: 64 bit,
Gnome: 43.1,
Windowing System: X11
```

However, this monitor receives no signal when connected. I have tested this monitor and cable on my windows desktop computer as well as MacBook and it is working, so its definitely not a issue with the monitor/cable.

Comment: Silly question, but have you tried the [Fn]+[F8] toggle? Some Huawei machines (and Dells) need to have the external monitor physically toggled via a keyboard combination before they can be used 

Comment: @matigo Have just tried as per your suggestion but no such luck.

Comment: Under Ubuntu 22.10, 5.19.17, updating the AMD drivers solved this issue for me (as well as not waking from suspend): [enter link description here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers)